# Schur property for a sum of Banach spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

Suppose we have two Banach spaces X and Y each of them having the [Schur property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_property) (weakly convergent sequences are norm convergent). Does it follows that X+Y has the Schur property? Note that this is trivially true when the sum is direct.

Any proof (or disproof), or references will be appreciated.

Comment: Meaning that they are both isometrically embedded in some Banach space $Z$ and you consider the closure of the linear span as the new space, or something else?

Comment: @fedja.  We can say that the pair (X,Y) is a compatible couple in the sense of interpolation theory: there is a Hausdorff topological vector space Z such that X and Y are subspaces of Z. The space X+Y is considered with the usual norm and is complete since both X,Y are complete. (to be more clear I am using the definition from p. 25 in Bergh, Lofstrom)